# ASP.NET Assembly Error binding logging off

Tags: asp.net

Hey just getting following error

Could not load file or assembly 'Ektron.Cms.Controls, Version=8.0.1.87, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=559a2c4fa21e63be' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

On line

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="LoggedIn.master.vb" Inherits="udpharmalecheile.LoggedIn" %>
```

With further information

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Ektron.Cms.Controls, Version=8.0.1.87, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=559a2c4fa21e63be' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Any Idea what I can do to resolve this ?

Comment: I was using two different versions of DLLs. Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using two different versions of DLLs. Solved